# Will a small unpaid medical bill prevent me from obtaining a US VISA? A B2 tourist visa to be exact

Tags: customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, tourist-visas

I have been to the US three times in the past, however I incurred a medical bill inndecember 2015, the bulk of the bill about $4500 has been paid by my insurance, however there is a small amount of about 500 dollars unpaid, was wondering if this would prevent me from getting another tourist visa? I do intend to settle my bill, have just been unable to as yet.

Do the consular official have access to medical bill information? And could my outstanding bill make seen as a public charge? I am currently a medical student so have a decent skill set, will this be in my favour?

Thanks and regards!

Urgent response required. Thanks.